# What is a term for a word or phrase whose literal wording differs from its actual meaning?

Tags: idioms

What is the definition of a word or phrase that does not describe properly what it is or does?
For example a black box flight recorder is not black but orange.
Are there any other examples of such words or phrases?

Comment: You seem to have already provided a definition :) . Are you looking for an *idiom* as the tag you used indicates, or are you looking for a *single-word-request*? Or perhaps you're looking for a more *rigorous* definition. Please edit your question to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

It's called a *misnomer* - the *name* doesn't match the *named*.

> **Misnomer** *noun*
>   A wrong or inaccurate name or designation: *‘King crab’ is a misnomer—these creatures are not crustaceans at all*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/misnomer)

Here are some examples from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misnomer):

- Catgut is made from sheep intestines.
- French horns originated in Germany, not France.
- The "funny bone" is not a bone—the phrase refers to the ulnar nerve.

Comment: And if the misnomer is wrong *enough*, it's an **oxymoron**, c.f. "dark light", "living dead", "open secret", and "Microsoft Works".

Answer (score 1):

In general this is called a [paradox](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paradox) or [contradiction](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contradiction). Your example is actually an outdated term as [originally](http://guardianlv.com/2014/03/why-are-cockpit-voice-recorders-painted-orange-and-called-a-black-box/) black boxes indeed were black.

**paradox**
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paradox

> A seemingly absurd or contradictory statement or proposition which when investigated may prove to be well founded or true:
>   *the uncertainty principle leads to all sorts of paradoxes, like the particles being in two places at once*

**contradiction**
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contradiction

> A combination of statements, ideas, or features which are opposed to one another:
>   *the proposed new system suffers from a set of internal contradictions*

**origin**
http://guardianlv.com/2014/03/why-are-cockpit-voice-recorders-painted-orange-and-called-a-black-box/

> While a modern-day black box is painted bright orange to help investigators find them, early versions were painted black, and the name stuck.

Comment: These don't fit the asker's example. "Orange" does not *contradict* "black": colors don't oppose one another because they're arbitrary points on a continuum, not extremes of a polarized range. Nor is a black box *paradoxical*: the statement "Modern black boxes are actually orange" is completely believable and understandable, not objectively absurd at all.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that this is an **[idiom](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/idioms/info)**:

> Idioms are a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words. Example of idioms are "rain cats and dogs" and "see the light."
>
> There are several lists of idioms on the Internet, including:
>
> - [Idioms and phrases](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/) from The Free Dictionary
> - [List of English-language idioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_idioms) in Wikipedia

It's all there in the tag definition on this very website!

Answer (score -2):

I can think of three examples immediately;

> elbow grease

which nothing to do with elbows or grease, but means hard physical work

> tennis elbow

which is an inflammation of the elbow area, but not always caused by tennis.

> monkey wrench

which is an adjustable wrench, unfortunately has very little to do with monkeys.

> Hot Dog

which isn't a dog, it's a sausage.

For a definition, I think I'd go with;

> **colloquialism** - a word or phrase that is not formal or literary and is used in ordinary or familiar conversation

Comment: Your examples are of things which are, at worst, orthogonal to the intended meaning rather than outright contradictory.  "Tennis elbow" may not *always* be caused by tennis, but it's obviously such a frequent occurrence that it adopted such a name.  The other two are metaphors which are at least descriptive.